# Cron Job Only Executes Once?

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

I am trying to create a quartz scheduler for cron jobs in Quartz.NET (*version 2.4.1.0*). I have one job that fires at its specified interval, and another that fires once in the start and never fires again (it also has a specified interval).
I am a little stumped as the only variation in these jobs is their names and CronSchedules (found in the triggers).

> **Note:** I have researched similar problems to this online (as well as Stack Overflow) and I have found nothing that solves my problem.
>   My DB connection works perfectly (UID/PWD left blank in this example).
>   All Cron Expressions have been tested in CronMaker and are valid.

#### App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </configSections>
  <quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value ="MyScheduler"/>
    <!--5 is recommended for under 100 jobs-->
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value ="5"/>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value =" false"/>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value ="false"/>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value ="60000"/>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value ="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz"/>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value ="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz"/>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value ="QRTZ_"/>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value ="myDS"/>
    <!--DB CONNECTION-->
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString" value ="Server=localhost;Database=QUARTZ;Uid=;Pwd="/>
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider" value ="SqlServer-20"/>
  </quartz>
</configuration>
```

#### Program.cs

> **Note:** Job 3 is successfully firing every minute. Job 4 fires once at the start and then stops firing (should be every 30 seconds).

Jobs:

```
public class Job3 : IJob
        {
            public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Job 3");
            }
        }

public class Job4 : IJob
        {
            public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Job 4");
            }
        }
```

Job Details:

```
IJobDetail jdJob3 = JobBuilder.Create<Job3>()
                        .WithIdentity("job3", "group3")
                        .WithDescription("CRON TRIGGER - Job meant to run constantly at 1min intervals")
                        .StoreDurably(true)
                        .Build();

IJobDetail jdJob4 = JobBuilder.Create<Job4>()
                        .WithIdentity("job4", "group3")
                        .WithDescription("CRON TRIGGER - Job meant to run constantly at 30sec intervals")
                        .StoreDurably(true)
                        .Build();
```

Triggers:

```
//Day Of Month - fires every minute
ITrigger tChron2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
     .WithIdentity("myTrigger3", "group3")
     .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?", x => x
          .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time"))
          .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()) //handle misfire
      .ForJob("job3", "group3")
      .Build();

//Day Of Month - fires every 30sec, between 8am and 2pm, on the 26th of every month, any year
ITrigger tChron3 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
     .WithIdentity("myTrigger4", "group3")
     .WithCronSchedule("0,30 * 8-14 26 * ?", x => x
          .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time"))
          .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()) //handle misfire
     .ForJob("job4", "group3")
     .Build();
```

Job Listener:

```
public class MyJobListener : IJobListener
    {
        void IJobListener.JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IJobListener.JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nJob is about to be executed...");
        }

        void IJobListener.JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job was executed...");
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

//IMPLEMENTATION    
MyJobListener myJobListener = new MyJobListener();
myJobListener.Name = "MyJobListener1";
scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(myJobListener, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());
```

#### OUTPUT

[image]

**Any ideas on what could be causing this?**

Comment: what is happen, if use the same cron schedule, as is used for job3?

Comment: @Set That's how I determined the problem listed in my answer below.  It would still operate the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pinpoint the issue.
I was not properly disposing my data from the database.

After running the project, I would delete all rows first from the **QRTZ_TRIGGERS** table, and then from the **QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS** table. This would allow me to run my project without receiving the error: "Unable to Store Job". What I didn't realize was that the **QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS** table was duplicating its fields for every consecutive run (I'm running different examples below):
[image]

This was causing conflicts when I would update the cron expressions as multiple instances of the same schedule existed.

To fix this, I utilized "ScheduleJobs" and set the replace value to true:

```
//JOB SCHEDULE CREATOR    
private static void JSCreator(IScheduler scheduler, IJobDetail jdJob, ITrigger tTrig)
            {
                var SJ = new Dictionary<IJobDetail, Quartz.Collection.ISet<ITrigger>>();
                SJ.Add(jdJob, new Quartz.Collection.HashSet<ITrigger>() { tTrig });
                scheduler.ScheduleJobs(SJ, true);
            }


 //IMPLEMENTATION
 JSCreator(scheduler, jdJob1, tSimple1);
 JSCreator(scheduler, jdJob2, tCron1);
 JSCreator(scheduler, jdJob3, tCron2);
 JSCreator(scheduler, jdJob4, tCron3);
 JSCreator(scheduler, jdJob5, tCron4);
 JSCreator(scheduler, jdJob6, tCron5);
```

This removed any existing data and replaced it with the data found in the job I was currently running. Now all of my jobs are running appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I can find nothing wrong with the code.

The only thing I can think of is that somehow your Job 4 ends up with an exception which is silently handled by Quartz, but keeps it from scheduling the next execution.

Maybe add a JobListener and see if you can use it to troubleshoot what is happening.

Comment: Added my job listener above.
I am handling JobExecutionVetoed and I still have the same problem.

Comment: can you add the output?

Comment: Just added the output

Comment: The problem makes sense, kudos on finding it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on utilizing a job listener. That was part of what helped me debug the issue.